# GRPC-GO:Client stub not shown in the generated pb.go file

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I am trying to learn GRPC from the official doc, Here is the tutorial I have followed [grpc-go](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/go/)

Generating the proto  using this command

```
protoc  --go_out=$PWD  helloworld/helloworld.proto
```

This above command will generate the file `helloworld.pb.go` without any problem but the problem is the code for the client stub is missing from the generated file

```
syntax = "proto3";
package helloworld;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

The actual error i am  getting from the client connection which is

> undefined: helloworld.NewGreeterClient

And this has occurred from the line `c := pb.NewGreeterClient(conn)` in the `greeter_client/main.go` file

The reason behind because the client stub not generated in the generated file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved i have some problems with the command

Here is the actual command

```
protoc   --go_out=plugins=grpc:$PWD helloworld.proto
```

Answer (score 0):

Add --I to your command. e.g.

```
protoc -I helloworld --go_out=${PWD} helloworld/*.proto
```

Comment: I don't think `-I` is necessary